# How can I add a function to this code that enable me to choose options from a pull-down menu?

Tags: javascript

I am reading the code of a forum, and curious about how can I improve the "ban" function from the code. Currently, when I want to ban someone, it will prompt a sentence and ask me write reasons. However, I want to know is there any way that I can choose what reasons I want to use, instead of write down by myself? For example, the different options are already shown so I do not need to write them by my self.

I was thinking about check-box or pull-down menu, but I am very new to Javascript. So,  I am wandering if someone can give me some help.

```
forbid_user: function(uid)
{
    AWS.dialog('textBox', {
        title: _t('Please write your reasons')
    }, function(text)
    {
        text = encodeURIComponent(text.trim());
        AWS.ajax_request(G_BASE_URL + '/account/ajax/forbid_user/' , 'uid=' + uid + '&status=1&reason=' + text);
    });
},
```

I want to know how to design a check box or pull down menu that I can use for the forbid_user function

Comment: Javascript has [33 keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords). Anything else you're using is a library. Please specify which library you are using so that you can get more targeted help.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: look at any example of checkbox or pull down menu and get to know it's API, then build your own,

A bit longer answer: on the page that executes `forbid_user` add a list of values that represent registered reasons, then extract selected value and put it in your request URL. Note that there's no code included in my answer; that's because you can get all the code and examples for free at any tech site